# Create table reference foreign key

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to create a table referencing a primary key from the table person;

```
CREATE TABLE Membership (foreign key (USERNAME) references Person(USERNAME),MembershipNo INT Primary Key,DatePaid date NOT NULL,DateTo date,AnnualFee INT NOT NULL)
                                      *
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-00904: "USERNAME": invalid identifier
```

I'm ether blind as a bat(possible) and there is a syntax error or I'm missing something.

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME='PERSON';

USERNAME     ROLE    DATEJOINED  ADDRESS     EMAILADDRESS    PHONENUMBER
```

`

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME='PERSON';

STUBT001     SYS_C00145052   P   PERSON                  ENABLED     NOT DEFERRABLE  IMMEDIATE   VALIDATED   GENERATED NAME          17-OCT-2013         SYS_C00145052
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't define a column `USERNAME` in your `MemberShip` table

```
CREATE TABLE Membership 
(
  MembershipNo INT Primary Key,
  DatePaid date NOT NULL,
  DateTo date,
  AnnualFee INT NOT NULL,
  username varchar(20) not null, -- << you are missing this
  foreign key (USERNAME) references Person(USERNAME)
);
```

alternatively directly behind the column:

```
CREATE TABLE Membership 
(
  MembershipNo INT Primary Key,
  DatePaid date NOT NULL,
  DateTo date,
  AnnualFee INT NOT NULL,
  username varchar(20) not null references Person(USERNAME)
);
```

Comment: Ah, great thanks, its been a while since I have needed to write a create table query. Thanks :)